# How to view a network generated with graph in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

I am trying to generate network and want to view it graphically.

I am using a list for storing edge information.

I have tried the following:

```
  from collections import defaultdict
class Graph(object):
    def __init__(self,connections):
        self.graph = defaultdict(set)
        self.addConnections(connections)

    def addConnections(self, connections):
        for node1, node2 in connections:
            self.addEdge(node1, node2)

    def addEdge(self, node1, node2):
        self.graph[node1].add(node2)

    def generateEdges(self): 
        edges = [] 
        for node in self.graph: 
            for neighbour in self.graph[node]: 
                edges.append((node, neighbour))
        self.edges = edges
        return edges
```

And I am trying to view the graph as follows:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from graph import Graph
#create edges for first graph
graph1Edges = [('A','B'), ('A', 'D'), ('B', 'C'), ('C','D')]
graph1 = Graph(graph1Edges)
nx.draw(graph1.generateEdges())
plt.show()
```

But, it is not working, please suggest me a way to do it as I don't want to use networkx package.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using networkx' graph implementation you tried to implement a Graph yourself and display it with networkx. This is of course not possible since `nx.draw` expects a networkx graph.

Simply remove your Graph implementation and run:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

edges = [('A', 'B'), ('A', 'D'), ('B', 'C'), ('C', 'D')]
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from(edges)
nx.draw_networkx(G)
plt.show()
```

And you'll get:

[image]

Comment: Yes, I want to implement Graph without using networkx package. Please help me with that context

Comment: @Anil but you did not mention that you do not want to use `networkx` in your question.

Comment: Networkx drawing API only works with networkx graphs. You can either convert your graph to a networkx graph, or use some drawing library (e.g., matplotlib) directly. I don't understand what you're trying to achieve. If you still want to use networkx drawing capabilities, but change the implementation for some functionalities, you can also inherit from networkx' `Graph` object.

Comment: @zohar.kom, Sorry for not mentioning in the question. **Yes, I don't want to use the networkx package**, I have used it in my above question to just try what will happen.

Comment: **I don't understand what you're trying to achieve**. Try reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and try to improve your question.